# Cypher Queries work in local machine but does not work in server . Also query works good in embedded mode but not in Rest mode

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The cypher queries that work fine in local machine (Windows) do not work in linux instance. The cypher queries also run great in embedded mode in the server/local but the same query does not work using the Rest mode (0 rows returned). The database size between local and server is hugely different, so are there any parameters we need to change in order of accomodate this difference in db size ?

I get a

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: 
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Example Queries are simple queries like: **match n where n:LABEL_BRANDS return n**  .

The properties in neo4j.properties file are:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M
```

Neo4J Version I use 2.0.0-RC1 .

Also I get a "**Disconnected from Neo4j. Please check if the chord is unplugged**" error on opening the browser interface very frequently.

Would there be a mistake in setting some properties in config files, could you identify the mistake here. Thanks .

Comment: upgrade your server Neo4j 2.0.0. If the problem persists, check your memory setup. For analysis, grab the latest startup sequence from your messages.log e.g. using https://gist.github.com/sarmbruster/8001713 and upload to pastebin.

Comment: I read in the messages.log : Total swap space : 0.00 B Free swap space : 0.00 B . While this is not the case in my local machine, do you think this is an issue ?  Another error I see when starting the Neo4j service is :  WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /db/manage/server/monitor/fetch
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
     ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upgrade to Neo4j 2.0
2. How big is the machine you run your Neo4j server on?
3. Try to configure a sensible amount of heap (8-16GB) and the rest of your RAM as memory-mapping according to the store-file sizes on disk
4. the query you've shown is a global scan which will return a lot of data over the wire on a large database. What are the actual graph queries/use-cases you want to run?
5. The error messages from the browsers also indicate that either your network setup is flaky or your server has issues. Please do upload your messages.log as Stefan has indicated to an accessible place and add the link to your question.

Comment: Hi, I upgraded the server to Neo4j2.0 , setting the heap size helped in success for certain queries not all. I created nodes using Cypher queries now, (earlier it was through embedded java) and the issue seems to be resolved, I am able to run the queries successfully in browser as well as using a Rest client. Only difference was the way I created nodes - Cypher vs embedded .

Comment: Ok, cool. then please accept the answer and close this question :)